# React Dynamic Get specific data while login with firebase

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, authentication

i want to know for example ,i have a page with name **client** and the user logged into the account from **account 1** , he should display from the database specific data ( client 1 data ) and **account 2** logged in and inside the same page he render another data , and for the **admin** he displays another data and so on , how can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Once the user is logged in, you can access their unique ID and use that to find documents related to their data.

Here is an example from the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query).

```js
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

db.collection("stories").where("author", "==", user.uid).get();
```

Comment: but what if i have alot of users , like 100 users and i want each one to see different data , this will be painful , should i use realtime database ? does it has the privilege to make for example each user has some role data that i can use it to render the page ?

the only problem with creating a user email password that it doesn't allow me to put another field for this situation

Comment: It shouldn't be painful to have >100 users each seeing different data. That is exactly what every medium-to-large scale web application can do with a database such as Firebase. You should not be creating the documents by hand, but rather creating them based on a default template when a user joins. Then the data is updated as the user continues to use your site. It should be seamless since you are creating and reading the document name from a template based on the user id.

Comment: but i cannot find a way to check if the user is able to see this data or not , for example with database i can do following ( id , user , pass , permission ) and filter the user depends on their permission what they can see with a select query but with firebase i cannot find something like this , should i use mongoDB for this case ? or firebase has something like this

Comment: MongoDB and Firebase both offer the same flexible schema solution, so there should not be any limitation on what you can achieve based on the shape of the data in Firebase. If you need some information to be available to users of different permission levels, then you can save that as a property of the user data and only display information at or above their permission level. I would highly recommend reading the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) and [docu-series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ) to learn more.